# How to use a cv2 image augmentation function with tensorflow tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I am using `tf.data.Dataset` to create my dataset and training a CNN with keras. I need to apply masks on the images, and the mask depends on the shape of the image, there are no predefined pixel coordinates.

When looking for an answer on the internet, I found that there are 2 ways of accessing shapes of images in TensorFlow (in training time):

1. Using eager execution (which is not enabled by default in my case, I'm using tf v 12.0)
2. Using a session

I do not want to use eager execution because it slows down training, and cannot use a session because I train and test the CNN using Keras (I feed the data to `model.train()` using iterators of `tf.data.Dataset`).

As a consequence, I have no way of knowing the shapes of images, and thus cannot access specific pixels for data augmentation.

I wrote a function using OpenCV (cv2) that applies the masks. Is there a way to integrate it with the TensorFlow data pipeline?

**EDIT** : I found a solution. I used **tf.py_func** to wrap the python functions

Comment: This question is off-topic here. Programming issues are generally off-topic here. See [https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. I will migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to transform elements of your dataset. You can then use `tf.py_function` to wrap your cv2 function into a tf op that executes eagerly. In tensorflow 1.x, you may use `tf.py_func` but the behavior is a bit different. See [tf.py_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function) documentation for more info.

So, in TF-2.x it will look something like:

```
def cv2_func(image, label):
    # your code goes here

def tf_cv2_func(image, label):
    [image, label] = tf.py_function(cv2_func, [image, label], [tf.float32, tf.float64])
    return image, label

train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).map(tf_cv2_func).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: Since you need image augmentation, I thought of supplying with some information on various image-augmentation libraries. This does not show you how to add OpenCV function into your tfdata-pipeline. But, if your requirements are standard enough, you may be able to use one of these:

- `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`
- `imaug`
- `albumentations`

## Data Augmentation in Python

1. Package: **`albumentations`**
   library: <kbd>external</kbd>
   url: [Python `albumentations` library](https://albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
2. Package: **`imaug`** :star:
   library: <kbd>external</kbd>
   url: [Python `imaug` library](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug)
3. Package: **`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`**
   library: <kbd>external</kbd>
   url: [Pyhon - TensorFlow `ImageDataGenerator` library](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

### Examples

1. Example(s)/use of **`albumentations`**.

   - url: [Example use-cases of `Albumentations`](https://albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)
2. Example(s)/use of **`imaug`**.

   - url: [Data Augmentation for Deep Learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-for-deep-learning-4fe21d1a4eb9) 
     :star::page_facing_up::heavy_check_mark: **Fantastic Article**
   - url: [Data Augmentation techniques in python](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-techniques-in-python-f216ef5eed69)
3. Example(s)/use of **`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`**.

   - url: [Official Example use-case of `tf.keras - ImageDataGenerator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#examples)
   - url: [Building powerful image classification models using very little data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)

Comment: Thanks for all these references! Do you know how to integrate imaug with the tensorflow input pipline (tfdata.Dataset)?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question though; you might find this useful: https://www.kaggle.com/rsk2327/densenet-imaug. 
See for iaa.<something> in the code. Mostly it is in get_seq() function.